# Find projectile speed given maximum height and range.

Tags: conic-sections, curves, kinematics, projectile-motion

I want to simulate a catapult throwing a rock in my computer game, but by design, I want all my units to shoot from a certain height, reach a maximum height and also hit a target that can be meters or kilometers away.

I tried solving the parabola needed for the equation using maths only since I was not able to do it with Kinematic formulas(I am not good at maths). For that, I solved the following system ([Interactive here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lgpxm4pmae)).

[image: Linear Equation]

Where the parabola is constrained to pass through $x_0$ (launch point) and $x_2$ target point, and halfway the derivative of the parabola must be $0$ so that there is a maximum (or minimum).

The problem is with that solution I cannot fix the height where the maximum is going to be. However, If I fit a parabola by scaling in $x$ and in $y$ I can achieve the desired constraints.

Can anyone briefly explain, why is it possible to find a set of kinematic equations that satisfy a parabola, that a linear system can't find a solution for?

Comment: Let me see if I understand:  in a nutshell, you want to find an equation for a parabola which passes through three points&mdash;an initial launch location, and a target, as well as a specific point at some height?

Comment: Yes, kind of. I want to find a parabola that passes through launch point, target point and middle point which should be at height H and also be a local maximum of the parabola. As I see it it is 4 equations for a linear system with three incognitas, not sure if it is doable.

Comment: So you want the projectile to achieve its maximum height exactly halfway between the launch point and target (on the horizontal axis)?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I am not being clear and thanks a lot for your response., Ideally I want all my units to be able to launch at different heights(always lower than the maxHeight) and reach different heights(also lower than maximum) as well since I have flying units. So yea, the parabola should reach the maximum height halfway in the range.

Comment: The precise thing you want is impossible unless the cannon and target are at the same height:  the maximum height of the parabola is at the vertex, and the parabola is symmetric about a vertical line through the vertex.  If you want that point to be half-way between, then the cannon and target must be symmetric across that line, so they must be at the same height.

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to develop a method for determining the path of motion of a projectile which is launched from a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and hits a target at $(x_2, y_2)$.  Because I want to *derive* the result, rather than trust some formula that I don't understand, I'm going to go through this from first principles.  This system can be modeled as follows:

I am going to assume, for concreteness, that distance is measured in meters, and that time is measured in seconds.  A projectile launched at time $t_0$ with initial velocity $(a,b)$ (that is, it is moving $a$ meters per second horizontally, and $b$ meters per second vertically) travels along a parabolic path given by
$$ q(t) = \left( at + x_0, -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + bt + y_0 \right), $$
where $q(t)$ is the projectile's position at time $t$, and $g$ is a gravitational constant (9.8 meters per second<sup>2</sup> on Earth, but we can make it whatever we want, I suppose).

This ultimately comes from a differential equation.  We know that the height, $y(t)$, satisfies $y''(t) = -g$, since the only force acting on the projectile is gravity.  Then
$$ \text{vertical velocity} = y'(t) = \int y''(t) = -gt + C, $$
where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Since we know that the initial velocity is $b$, we have $b = y'(0) = C$, so $y'(t) = -gt + b$.  Similarly,
$$ \text{height} = y(t) = \int y'(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + bt + C, $$
where $C$ is another constant of integration which, in this case, turns out to be $y_0$.  This explains the $y$-coordinate of the position function $q$.  Similar arguments give the $x$-coordinate, where we assume that no force is acting in the horizontal direction—the projectile just moves with a constant velocity of $x'(t) = a$.

Without loss of generality, suppose that the projectile is launched at time $t=0$, and hits its target at time $t_t$.  By construction, $q(0) = (x_0, y_0)$.  We also need
$$ q(t_t) = \left( at_t + x_0, -\frac{1}{2} g t_t^2 + bt_t + y_0 \right) = (x_2, y_2). \tag{1}$$
Finally, we want the projectile to reach its maximum height at $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_0 + x_2)$.  While more elementary tools will get the job done, this happens when the vertical velocity is zero, i.e. when
\begin{align}
q'(t_m) &= \left( a, -gt_m + b \right) = \left( a, 0 \right), \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $t_m$ denotes the time at which the projectile reaches its maximum height. 
 Putting this together, we have several quantities running around:

- $a$, the initial horizontal velocity,
- $b$, the initial vertical velocity),
- $t_t$, the time that that projectile hits the target,
- $t_m$, the time at which the projectile hits its maximum height, and
- $g$, the gravitational constant.

In a realistic setting, we aren't going to have much control over anything other than the initial velocity (for example, you can control how much powder you put in your cannon, but not much else).  Then (1) and (2) imply that
\begin{align}
at_t + x_0 &= x_2, \tag{4}\\
-\tfrac{1}{2}gt_t^2 + bt_t + y_0 &= y_2, \tag{5}\\
-gt_m + b &= 0. \tag{6}
\end{align}
There are four unknowns here ($a$, $b$, $t_m$, and $t_t$), and three equations, so there is hope, but if we get any solution, there will be infinitely many more solutions—we will have some free parameter that we will have to choose.

Equations (4) and (6) give
$$
\boxed{a = \frac{x_2-x_0}{t_t}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\boxed{b = gt_m}.
$$
To get a relation between $t_m$ and $t_t$, substitute $b=gt_m$ into (5) and solve for one of either $t_m$ or $t_t$ (you can go either way:  solving for $t_m$ let's you determine when the projectile reaches its maximum height, while solving for $t_t$ let's you determine the time at which you hit your target).  Getting $t_m$ in terms of $t_t$ is relatively straight-forward (and seems the natural thing to want to do):
$$
-\frac{1}{2}gt_t^2 + gt_mt_t + y_0 = y_2
\implies \boxed{ t_m = \frac{y_2 - y_0 + \frac{1}{2}gt_t^2}{gt_t} }. \tag{7}
$$
If you need to determine the maximum height from this, evaluate $q(t_m)$, and look at the $y$-coordinate.  Here is a [Desmos demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/piqapoumo6) which models this situation—you can drag either the cannon or the target around, and use the slider to adjust the time-to-target.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I am taking my time understanding all of it!

Answer (score 0):

With a translation we can always carry the launch point to the origin (i.e. $x_0=y_0=0$). In that case the parabola has general equation $y=ax^2+bx$; as it passes through the target point $(x_2,y_2)$ we have a first equation for $a$ and $b$:
$$
\tag{1}
y_2=ax_2^2+bx_2.
$$
In addition, the vertex of the parabola has its ordinate fixed at $y_M$ (maximum height), which gives a second equation:
$$
\tag{2}
y_M=-{b^2\over4a}.
$$
We can solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $a$ and $b$ to find:
$$
b=2{y_M\pm\sqrt{y_M(y_M-y_2)}\over x_2},\quad
a={y_2\over x_2^2}-{b\over x_2}.
$$
There are two solutions, but only for one of them the abscissa $x_M=-{b\over2a}$ of the vertex lies between $0$ and $x_2$, which is the case of interest. This "good" solution is usually the one obtained by taking sign $+$ in the formula for $b$. 
Notice, however, that $x_M$ is the midpoint between $x_0$ and $x_2$ only if $y_0=y_2$.

Launch angle $\theta$ can be found from
$$
\tan\theta={dy\over dx}\Big|_{x=0}=b.
$$

Finally, to compute the initial speed of the rock we can use the conservation of energy:

$$
{1\over2}mv^2=mgy_M+{1\over2}m(v\cos\theta)^2,
\quad\text{whence:}\quad
v={\sqrt{2gy_M}\over\sin\theta},
$$
where $g=9.80\ \text{m/s}^2$.

You can now switch back the translation, if you want, by replacing any $x_*$ with $x_*-x_1$ and any $y_*$ with $y_*-y_1$ in all formulas above (included the equation of the parabola).

Answer (score 0):

With

$$
Y = A x^2+B x+ C
$$

Giving the due points $(x_0,Y_0), (x_1, Y_1), (x_m, Y_m)$ where

$$
\left(\frac{dY}{dx}\right)_{x=x_m} = 0 = 2A x_m + B
$$

we have the formulas

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
A & = & \frac{Y_1+Y_2-2 \left(Y_m+\sqrt{\left(Y_1-Y_m\right) \left(Y_2-Y_m\right)}\right)}{\left(x_1-x_2\right){}^2}\\
B & = & \frac{2 \left(x_2 \left(Y_m+\sqrt{\left(Y_1-Y_m\right) \left(Y_2-Y_m\right)}-Y_1\right)+x_1 \left(Y_m+\sqrt{\left(Y_1-Y_m\right)
   \left(Y_2-Y_m\right)}-Y_2\right)\right)}{\left(x_1-x_2\right){}^2}\\
C & = & Y_m + \frac{B^2}{4A}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

NOTE

Those formulas where obtained as follows.

From  $x_m = -\frac{B}{2A}$ and substituting into

$$
 Y_m-A x_m^2-B x_m-C=0 \\
$$

we get

$$ 
C = Y_m + \frac{B^2}{4A}
$$

and now solving for $A,B$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 Y_1 = A x_1^2+B x_1+Y_m + \frac{B^2}{4A} \\
 Y_2 = A x_2^2+B x_2+Y_m + \frac{B^2}{4A}\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

after some algebra we obtain the formulas.

As an application, giving $x_1 = 2, Y_1 = 1, x_2 = 10, Y_2 = 10, Y_m = 11$ we obtain

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 A&=&\frac{1}{64} \left(11-2 \left(11+\sqrt{10}\right)\right) \\
 B&=& \frac{1}{32} \left(2 \left(1+\sqrt{10}\right)+10 \left(10+\sqrt{10}\right)\right) \\
 C&=&\frac{28800-40 \left(1200+64 \sqrt{10}\right)}{4096} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

[image]